# Adjusting spacing in beamer while changing font size

Tags: beamer, line-spacing

If I decrease the font size in `beamer`, as in the code below, the spacing stays the same.  I do want single spacing throughout, but adjusted according to the specific font size being employed.  That is, I want smaller fonts to be closer together vertically than bigger fonts.  How can I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{tiny}
\blindtext
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Issue an ending `\par`: `\blindtext\par`

Answer (score 6):

Issue a manual `\par` within the `tiny` block to force the paragraph to be set using the `\tiny` specification. However, you can avoid this by using a `\parbox` directly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\parbox{\linewidth}{\tiny
  \blindtext}

\end{document}
```